# iTunes plays songs one at a time when stored on external drive

Tags: itunes

I store all my music on an external hard drive. When I click on an album iTunes opens but only plays one track. Is there any way I can play a whole album or multiple albums?

Comment: Are you using Shuffle mode, if so then it may happen when some Files have been moved on your external Drive but in the iTunes Library there is still the old place linked. I recommend you to use one of Doug's Applescript which can search your iTunes files that aren't there anymore http://dougscripts.com/123

Answer (score 1):

Given that you say you're clicking on an album, and iTunes opens, it sounds like you're playing your music from the Finder folder, and not using iTunes itself. If you double-click a song, even if it's within the album's folder, you're just asking for that song.

Once iTunes is open, if you double-click and play a song from iTunes, it'll keep playing the whole album, or whole selection of songs that you've chosen.